# How to load about 50GB files into Mongo when using Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm doing a Meteor project right now. There'a json file of about 50 GB I need to read into the server and create a collection. It gave me an error of buffer length so I suppose it is impossible to directly do so. Any suggestions on it? Thanks!

Comment: You could write an importer that reads objects one at a time from the file and then does `collection.insert()`

Comment: there is a Japanese proverb - you can eat an elephant - but never do it at once... try to read files in chunks